# Not sure why I keep getting 404 error with Ruby Rest Client

Tags: ruby, json, rest

I'm using the following code:

```
RestClient.get "https://myurl.com/apps/v1/company/apps/appname/device/#{device_uuid}", :params => {:client_id => client_id, :client_secret => client_secret} do |response, request, result, &block|
  if [404].include? response.code
    puts 'ERROR' + response.body
  else
    response.return!(request, result, &block)
  end
end
```

I am trying to use client_id and client_secret as query string parameters, and I know that when I manually do a get on this url in my browser that it is valid - however when I try to use this rest client get request, I only seem to be getting a 404 resource not found back.

The end result I am trying to do is to get the JSON back from this get request as well - it may need to be a separate question but I am also having issues with getting the JSON contents from the response body.

Thank you for any help

Comment: are the logs showing anything different between the requests?

Comment: No, only 404 Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)

If I put the whole URL in without grabbing the variables - I get the same thing, but then putting that URL in to my web browser it is fine

Comment: I meant the logs for the server that has the API

Comment: I was able to figure it out with a little more work - for some reason it was returning a 404 until I set :accept => :json as an argument

Answer (score 0):

The code from above worked better as:

```
response = RestClient.get "https://myurl.com/apps/v1/company/apps/app1/devices/#device_uuid}",
                                {:params => {:client_id => client_id, :client_secret => client_secret}, :accept => :json}
```

It was not just adding the :accept => :json but also making sure it was passed along as part of my parameters - no idea why it bubbled up as a 404 though.